# How to change a button value from "buttonX" to "clicked" on clicked?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

This is a homework that I'll have to create a "x" amount of buttons and when I click on any button, it should change its value/label from "buttonX" to "clicked".
By clicking in another button, the first will reset to "buttonX" and the new button will change to "clicked".
So far I was able to create the "x" amount of buttons, but I dont know how to make them clickable to change its value back and forth.

Here's my model:

```
namespace buttonTag.Models {
    public class Button {
        private const int QTY_BTN = 10;

        public Button() {

        }

        public int buttons {
            get {
                return QTY_BTN;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my Razor page:

```
@model buttonTag.Models.Button;

<form asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Button">
    <div class="form-group">
        @{
            for(int i=1; i<@Model.buttons + 1; i++) {
                <input type="submit" value=@("Button" + i) class="btn btn-primary ml-4 mb-4" />
            }
        }
    </div>

</form>
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple workaround like below:

```
<form asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Button">
    <div class="form-group">
        @{
            for (int i = 1; i < @Model.buttons + 1; i++)
            {
                <input type="button" id="@i" value=@("Button" + i) class="btn btn-primary ml-4 mb-4" onclick="Test(@i)" />
            }
        }
    </div>

</form>
@section Scripts{ 
<script>
    var item;
    function Test(i) {
        if (i != item) {
            if (($("#" + i)).val().startsWith('Button')) {
                $("#" + i).val("Clicked");
            }
        }      
        $("#" + item).val("Button" + item);
        item = i;
        return item;
    }

</script>
}
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Omg! Thank you very much!